# Get an image from a web service with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest

I want to get an image from a web service. The connection to the web service is done successfully, but the image is not opened in my phoneGap application or it opened in Mozilla...
This is my code:

```
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.open("GET",'http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=motdepasse&ws_key=login',true);

            request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState==4)
                    {

                       if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
                        {


             alert("Status2 is  "+request.status);
                document.getElementById("myimg").src='http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=motdepasse&ws_key=login';

                        }
                     }

                 }
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: You cannot do cross domain access like that. For the .src you can but then it asks for a userID and password. Or are you already logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u able to get an Image using this URL

http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=motdepasse&ws_key=login

If yes then what you can do is give this `<img src="http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=motdepasse&ws_key=login"` in your HTML.

There is no need for Ajax to do that if you get the Image with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Or even

`<img src="http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=motdepasse&ws_key=login" onError="this.src='productorservernotavailable.gif'" />`

Comment: SHOP_URL/api/images/products/1/1?ws_key=2345NLL382NVSCBAECULTKHV4K9CKM3M 
what is PHP_AUTH_USER ?

Comment: It was in the URL of the original question